# Как сохранять данные HTTP-сессии между activities Android-приложения

Tags: android, kotlin, http, flask, сессия

пишу приложение для Android, имеется свой написанный сервер на Flask с использованием Sessions. Для запросов использую библиотеку Fuel. Есть два активити: Логин и Последние сообщения. На первом активити я вызываю запрос на логин, сервер создает сессию, но при переходе на новое активити (Последние сообщения), данные о сессии не передаются (приходит ошибка с сервера, что пользователь не аутентифицирован) и получить список последних сообщений не удается. Хотелось бы узнать как правильно реализовать работу HTTP, чтобы данные об авторизации переходили из одного активити в другое.

Comment: Вам нужно самому заботиться о сохранении сессии в виде кукис или еще чего между запросами. Насколько мне известно, ни одна из известных сетевых библиотек из коробки это не поддерживает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я правильно понимаю, что у вас проблема именно в использовании библиотеки? Так-то сессия - это просто абстракция, обычно представленная в виде строчки, которая в заголовке запроса передаётся. В вэбе для удобства заголовки запросов/ответов с Cookie в имени заголовка называют куками. Когда вы получаете на клиенте сессию - на самом деле вам в ответе сервера приходит строчка в заголовке Set-Cookie. Прикреплять же сессию к запросам надо через добавление значения  понянутого заголовка в заголовок Cookie. Вот и вся магия. Получите сессию, сохраните и крепите к каждому запросу

Comment: Спасибо, огромное, собирался уже делать ограничения со стороны клиента :) А гуглить не зная, что именно хочу найти затея глупая, ещё раз спасибо!